How to distinguish between two different terminal exit statuses?
Consider the following example:
term_start(myprogram, {exit_cb: MyExitHandler})

def MyExitHandler()
  if exit_status != 0
    echom "Error!"
  endif
enddef

The function MyExitHandler is called when myprogram encounter some error OR when I wipe out the terminal buffer running myprogram.
In both cases echom "Error!" is run. The program myprogram has only two exit statuses: 0 (success) and 1 (failure).
Is there a way where I can distinguish when myprogram detect an error and when the terminal buffer is wiped out so that I can have two different messages? If so how?

See :help term_setkill(), :help term_getjob(), and :help job_info().
